# Is it possible to show small alerts in the upper right corner on Apple TV? (like the "remote connected")

Tags: notifications, alert, tvos, apple-tv, tvos10

I want to show a small notification while my tvOS App is running. The normal UIAlertController alerts are fullscreen and would be disturbing the experience.

Is there a way to use the notifications, which tvOS shows when the remote is connected and so on? They look appear in the upper right corner for a few seconds as an overlay.

Thank You

Comment: That sounds like a push notification or local notification. However, if your app is currently in the foreground the system won't display that UI. You could do something similar by hand.